# Where are the Serial functions in Arduino defined?

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

In which file are the Serial functions like .begin(), .flush(), and all the others referenced here arduino.cc/en/Reference/Serial actually defined?

In AndroidStudio, you can just Control+Click on a method and it opens the file where that method is defined. Why do things have to be so difficult with the Arduino IDE? Is there an alternative IDE for Arduino that enables one to delve deeply into the arduino core without spending hours searching for the files where things are defined.

EDIT:
"Eclipse for Arduino" did the trick for me. You can just Control+Click on a function and it opens its definition.

Comment: There are alternatives to using the somewhat rudimentary Arduino environment described at http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DevelopmentTools, and also discussed [here](https://www.intorobotics.com/alternatives-standard-arduino-ide-one-choose/) including Eclipse and Visual Studio which certainly have powerful code navigation and browsing tools including "go to definition". How well it works in this instance will depend on whether the definitions are visible - if the source is compiled and linked they will be, if object code is linked, they won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked, and it's in hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.h
However, the Arduino compiler is set up to automatically include the necessary headers (possibly via Arduino.h in the same directory), so you don't actually need to include anything in order to use it.

Comment: That is where they are *declared* rather than *defined*.

Comment: True, the actual Serial object is defined in HardwareSerial0.cpp, while begin()/flush() are in HardwareSerial.cpp. However, I'm guessing that he's more interested in the declaration. IIRC, Ctrl+Clicking on a method in Android Studio jumps to its declaration.

Comment: May be but you could use the the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Begin) for that - or at least you could if te Arduino documentation did not have such a scant regard for specifying argument data types!